# Broadkam ADSL modem USB driver not available

Tags: windows-7, networking, usb, drivers, adsl

I have had an ADSL modem (Broadkam PJ871 Combo Router/Modem) for around 7 years. At that time, although the driver was with its package, I could find its formal web page and download the driver directly from it. However, now it is not available and I could not find it anywhere else.

Is there anyway to make it work without the driver? Simply plugging it with the USB cable did not work in Windows 7.

Comment: Ok, I have added the model now. The problem is  cant remember the previous URL that was supposed to be the official Web page of the company.

Comment: Lead me to some page with this URL (http://www.gamaneh.ir/404.php) and `nothing` as its text.

Comment: Depending on your bitness (64 or 32). You may be able to get away with using the matching windows xp driver for it.

Comment: @mt025 do you mind to tell me how?

Comment: I misread your question a little, and now see that you can find any driver for it. Try searching for the device ID. First section in guide here http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-unknown-device-drivers-by-their-vendor-device-id/